# Passing scope data from a function to parent scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my controller I have a $http call which returns a json string which I then want to pass to a directive to be added to a map. The string is being passed from the controller to the directive fine but not from from the $http function within the controller to the directive.

```
 wmm.controller('wapMapClr', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$window', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $window, $http) {

$scope.geobj = {};
$scope.geobj.geoprop = ""

// Search by postcode
// create a blank object to hold our form information
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.pcSearch = function () {
$scope.data = {};

$http.post('api/api.php', { postcode: $scope.formData } )
    .success(function (result) {

       $scope.geobj = {geoprop : result.json_string};
      console.log($scope.geobj.geoprop);
```

Any help would really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Hi I didn't get any error - just empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`Promises` are asynchronous, so you don't know when the `promise` returns, so it won't be immediately available for you

1. Your directive has a `controller` method, from where you can fire the `$http` call which you can access.
2. You can use `$emit/$brodcast` to listen to events passed from `controller` to your directive.

I am not sure what error you get, here is a fiddle with `$timeout` used which is `async` which works.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{obj.prop}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.obj = { prop: "world" };
    $timeout(function(){
       $scope.obj = { prop: "from timeout" };
    },10000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jt6j82by/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Thalaivar. I modified the code you gave and it worked. See below:

```
wmm.controller('wapMapClr', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', function ($scope, $window, $http) {

$scope.geobj = {};

// Search by postcode
// create a blank object to hold our form information
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.pcSearch = function () {
$scope.data = {};

$http.post('api/api.php', { postcode: $scope.formData } )
    .success(function (result) {

        $scope.geobj = {geoprop : result.json_string};
```

Then in the directive...

```
wmm.directive('tchOlMap', function () {

    var MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID = 'tchMap';

    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        //BELOW IS THE LINE I CHANGED TO MAKE IT WORK!
        scope: false,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="' + MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID + '" class="full-height"></div>',

        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
```